# Aggregate total Descendants using CTE MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a very simple table in a Micrososft SQL 2008 R2 database called "Ancestry" of the form:

> parentSearch  childSearch
>  1195784 1185596
>  1195787 1185596
>   1195787   1195785
>  1195787 1195786
>  1195799 1185596
>   1185596   1195785
>  1195785 1195786
>  1195786 1195776
>   1195786   1195788
>  1195786 1195790
>  1195786 1195796
>   1195786   1195798
>  1195785 1195786
>  1195786 1195776
>   1195786   1195788
>  1195786 1195790
>  1195786 1195796
>   1195786   1195798
>  1195786 1195776
>  1195786 1195788
>   1195786   1195790
>  1195786 1195796
>  1195786 1195798

This is an ancestry table, with descendants at least four levels deep.  I have beat myself blue inthe face trying to write a CTE against this that will aggregate the total number of descendants for EACH parent, nom atter the level they are at.  A single child in this data can have multiple parents.

Comment: Can you post code what you have tried so far?

Comment: Or how 'bout just an example of what you you expect the output to be, given that input.

Comment: OK...and I am just make up numbers here....each number represents a parent.<br>1110987    2<br>

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
with temp as
(
SELECT 1195784 as Parent, 1185596 as Child
UNION
SELECT 1195787, 1185596
UNION
SELECT 1195787, 1195785
UNION
SELECT 1195787, 1195786
UNION
SELECT 1195799, 1185596
UNION
SELECT 1185596, 1195785
UNION
SELECT 1195785, 1195786
UNION
SELECT 1195786, 1195776
UNION
SELECT 1195786, 1195788
UNION
SELECT 1195786, 1195790
UNION
SELECT 1195786, 1195796
UNION
SELECT 1195786, 1195798
UNION
SELECT 1195785, 1195786
UNION
SELECT 1195786, 1195776
UNION
SELECT 1195786, 1195788
UNION
SELECT 1195786, 1195790
UNION
SELECT 1195786, 1195796
UNION
SELECT 1195786, 1195798
UNION
SELECT 1195786, 1195776
UNION
SELECT 1195786, 1195788
UNION
SELECT 1195786, 1195790
UNION
SELECT 1195786, 1195796
UNION
SELECT 1195786, 1195798
),
agg as
(
        SELECT  parent, child
        FROM    temp
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  t.parent, t.Child
        FROM    agg
        JOIN    temp t
        ON      agg.child = t.parent
)

SELECT parent, COUNT(*)
FROM agg
GROUP BY parent
```

Comment: Ups, my answer came 5 minutes too late. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Ancestry
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A.ParentSearch, B.ChildSearch
    FROM CTE A
    INNER JOIN Ancestry B
    ON A.ChildSearch = B.ParentSearch
)
SELECT ParentSearch, COUNT(*) Quant
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ParentSearch
ORDER BY ParentSearch
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Lamak, I tried it out and it yielded this, which is not the right answer:1185596 33 1195784 34 1195785 32 1195786 15 1195787 83 1195799 34 1195800 33

Comment: P.S. ow on earth do you get line breaks in these things??? (am new to stackoverflow but am not liking the way my comments look.."

Comment: @user74456 - That's weird, I actually tested the code before posting, and the results were correct. (and about the comments, it is difficult to format them correctly)